# how to read variables in bash and pass these variables to a c++ program as arguments

Tags: shell-script, c++

I am trying to read a few vars in my bash script and pass these to a C++ program which will accept these variables as arguments. any help please? I got this far..but it does not work...

```
echo -n 'Enter a name: '
read name
echo -n 'Enter a lastname: '
read lastname
./myprogram "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

**First Solution:**
Write following lines in your script file like `myscript.sh` and execute your script without any parameters like `./myscript.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter your name: " name
read -p "Enter your lastname: lastname
./myprogram "${name}" "${lastname}"
```

**NOTE:** In the upper script you prompted to enter name and lastname and stored in variables then passed to your C++ program.

**Second Solution:**
Write following lines in your script and pass your parameters to your script like `./myscript.sh foo bar`

```
#!/bin/bash   

./myprogram "$@"
```

**NOTE:** In the upper script you passed your parameters to shell script and it passed all of parameters to your C++ program directly.